# How do I retrieve data from Firebase into Unity3d via JSON?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I hope I'm going to make my question as clear as possible. 
Basically

- I have a list of hundreds of items saved in my FirebaseDatabse.
- I convert the data to a JSON
- Now I want to use that JSON and apply all the data into different items in the unity scene

I have tried to read all nodes/items in my firebase child section, and I also declared 'foreach' method to do something with each child it faces. But it does not work when I want to call another class or function inside the 'foreach' method and I have no idea why it does not!

I really appreciate any help or idea to achieve it.
If possible I want to make a 'foreach' method and deal with each item differently because the key is different so does the value of each item present in the JSON.

````
Player.Child(UserId).Child("User_Inventory").Child("Items").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Handle the error...
                Debug.LogError("Could not finish (LoadPlayerData) !!");
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                      // here is the data for all the items that I have

                    string JSON = snapshot.GetRawJsonValue();

               // Now How can I deal with each key/item present in the JSON?

       ```
````

---

---

### **[Update]**

```
public void RetrieveData () {
Player.Child(UserId)
            .Child("User_Inventory").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Handle the error...
                Debug.LogError("Could not finish (LoadPlayerData) !!");
            }
            else if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;

                    foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
                {
                   print(Child); // shows only one child's data when the  below 
                                 //line of code is present!!
                   DisplayInfo(Child.Key, (int)Child.Value);

                }
}});
}


public GameObject Item;
public GameObject Contents;
public void DisplayInfo(string Name, int quantity)
    {


        Item = Contents.transform.parent.Find(Name).GetComponent<QTY_UI>();
        Item.Qty = quantity;  // just passing quantity to another class



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than convert your firebase data to a RawJson and trying to iterate the JSON object, you can iterate through the children of the snapshot directly. You can iterate through children of children in the same manner.

```
if(task.IsCompleted)
{
    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
    foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
    {
        string key = child.Key;
        string value = child.Value;
        //Process child here.
    }
}
```

## Update:

Try this to get your children in a more manageable format

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (DataSnapshot child in snapshot.Children)
{
    dict.Add(child.Key, child.Value);
}
//dict now contains all of your json children as a dictionary reference.
```

Comment: Hello, thank you Erik for your reply. I have done that and I get the child key&value with no problem however If I try to pass the child key&value to another class, it does not happen!

Comment: And if we try to get 'child.value' as a string, it gives an error because the 'value' considered to be an object. [ Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string]

Comment: Sorry, my post here assumes you are parsing your bottom-level node. If your child is not the bottom level node, you will need to parse it as a JSON object or a Dictionary<String, Object> to read from it.

Comment: Well, actually it's, I'm trying to get the bottom-level node but I have those problems that I mentioned, I can't pass the data. I think inside an iterator like 'foreach' we can't call another function?!

Comment: Let's say I have a child  that has items with integer being their value, I will instantiate each child item as a prefab or whatever in my unity and get the item's key and value and to do that I use an iterator. This is my mission and I only struggle getting the value of the item which is an int. I also tried  int myValue = (int) Child.Value;  Still Nothing happens!

Comment: @Aron You can call other functions from within the foreach method. Please add onto your post the code where you are trying to cast the data back to a gameObject. You will need to explicitly retrieve the values from your snapshot. I've added some extra code that may help you.

Comment: I added the codes please have a look and inform me of anything I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try Convert.ToInt32(Child.Value) @Aron

Comment: Still not working! I even tested on my phone, the problem is, the function 'DisplayInfo' isn't getting any call!!

Comment: Can you share your firebase DB structure @Aron

Comment: Also, it looks like you used a capital C "Child" instead of lower case c "child" in your for loop. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I may have missed that during the copy&paste of the codes. It's been a couple of days I'm trying different ways but unfortunately, none of them worked!
The main problem is, inside the loop I can never perform "Find game object" to find a gameobject based on "child.key" and then passing its value. I would be thankful if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I'm sure there is no problem in the way I use firebase, It's just an inability to deal with single child that has been retrieved from the database. 
I need to find (x) gameObject based on (x)name of the child and for that as you know I used a loop method, inside it I just can't perform the task of finding a gameobject in the scene!

Comment: You cannot call GameObject.Find or any other native Unity methods within the task, because the task is technically running asynchronously (and therefore can't access the main thread). You would need to pass the snapshot data to a place outside of the task in order to perform GameObject.Find or anything like that.

Comment: I even tried this, even if I try to pass the data into another function and use that function to find the gameobject, that did not work either :(. I'm sad about why unity offers such problems. What other  way do you think is good for retrieving data and passing them into objects  I'm looking for a quick way. Thank you so much for your time <3

Comment: @Aron just because you pass to another function, doesn't mean you've left the scope of the original function. You would need to process the data AFTER the task is completed.

Comment: Finally, I created a  dictionary in the script that retrieves the data from the database and the data is put into the dictionary, and inside unity each item (prefab) has another script that gets fired up whenever the event in the other script is triggered and the item uses its name to find & look for its value inside the dictionary. Everything now is fine but I'm nervous about that maybe there is a better and faster way to do the same. I really apprecate your time man thank you so much.

Comment: Unity can be confusing at times because everything is synchronous on the main thread. Running asynchronous tasks can be confusing at first. You could consider looking into Firebase's OnChildChanged functionality to have each child trigger individually instead of through a foreach. I believe OnChildChanged is called for every child at the start of the script. Good luck!

Comment: I have no idea why I did not try this. I actually tried ChildChange Method and now Everything works pretty well. I'm doing 1) subscribing to the node that has the child's and when any child gets updated in the database, it will make the change in unity instantly (the thing I was looking for). AND THANK YOU so much for that insight I really appreciate it. I still use a foreach method with dictionary  only for the start of the game in order to load the data in the database and it seems to be the only way to do that, I would also want to know if there is a better way?!

Comment: Loading everything using ForEach once at the start of the game is probably the best way to handle it in my opinion. I believe the ValueChanged listener triggers once at the start of listening, and then any changes after it. However, I believe that only happens for ValueChanged and not the ChildChange listeners.

Comment: You made everything clear, do you think it's cost-y to have many listeners in the game retrieving different child in the database?

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a ton of listeners. That being said, as long as you are creating all of your listeners at the start, and not dynamically creating them as you go or as the database changes, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much Erik, much appreciate your kind help!